# interaction between AngularJS $http and [WebMethod]/[ScriptMethod] on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I'm begginer in AngularJS and i work on project  developped with ASP.NET that allow extraction of xml content  file and display in Angularjs data.

My C# code is:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string publishMD(List<Dictionary<string, object>> childArray)
{
    // Convertir le Dic en Json
    string myJsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(childArray);
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\fatima.bouazza\Documents\XML\ff.txt"))
    {
        file.WriteLine(myJsonString);
    }

    //envoi à la fonction angularJS
  ');", true);  

    return myJsonString;
}
```

and AngularJS:

```
    angular.module('myapp', []).controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http) {


    var vm = this;
    vm.mydata = [];

    $http.get('mon-formulaire.aspx/publishMD').success(function (result) {
        vm.myData = result.data;
        console.log(result);
    });



    $http.Post('mon-formulaire.aspx/publishMD', { data: {} })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.myData = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("error");
        });

}).config(function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

});
```

My AngularJS function can not display the content of XML which is converted into JSON array. Why does that happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: I reformatted a little the code you provided. It looks strange. Did you copy&paste it twice accidentally, or do you really have it written twice?

Comment: sorry, is copy and paste it twice, i'm new on stacjoverflow lol